# No puedo instalar hMailServer ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Tags: php, phpmailer, microsoft

saludos :) estoy realizando la programación de una Landing Page para adquirir experiencia con PHP, y se me ha enfrentado un  problema: quiero enviar un correo por medio de un formulario, es decir, si un cliente se contacta con la pagina, este le llegue un correo de con un mensaje que su solicitud está siendo procesada y cosas aquí (nada importante) y he investigado la manera de enviar ese correo por medio de código y sé que se debe de instalar un SMTP, el cual yo he escogido hMailServer.

Sin embargo, al momento de descargarlo y tratar de instalarlo, para los que ya lo tienen, al momento de llegar a este paso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y le doy clic en 'Install' e instalar Microsoft .NEt FrameWork 2.0, me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pudieran decirme que puedo hacer, ¿ o hay de otra manera mejor para que yo pueda hacer uso en PHP para enviar correos?

De antemano muchas gracias :)

Comment: hMailServer es para crear un servidor de correos, y no quieres eso. Usa [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), es una forma sencilla y multiplataforma de enviar correos desde tu aplicación PHP. No necesitas *composer* para instalarlo, solo copia el directorio `src` y de ahí incluyes los módulos respectivos en tu desarrollo. Hay mucha documentación [en internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=configurar+phpmailer) de cómo usarlo, incluso [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+phpmailer) y [allá](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+phpmailer). Saludos.